# Zeppelin & spark.ipyspark & folium

Tags: python, pyspark, ipython, apache-zeppelin, folium

I really like how folium works with python on jupyter notebooks (I haven't tried it, but judging from the tutorials). What I want to achieve is same functionality, but with zeppelin notebooks using spark.ipyspark. Folium functionality would be huge improvement of data plotting capabilities of zeppelin's notebooks.

What I tried is simple:

```
import folium
m = folium.Map(location=[45.5236, -122.6750])
m
```

This is only returning `<folium.folium.Map at 0x10f4a3518>`

What I tried next is to build HTML map, save it locally and then invoke it as output of zeppelin paragraph.

```
import folium
from IPython.display import HTML
from IPython.display import IFrame


m =folium.Map(
location=[45.5236, -122.6750],
tiles='Stamen Toner',
zoom_start=13
)

m.render_iframe = True
m.save('/Users/abc/m.html')

HTML("<iframe src=file:///Users/abc/m.html width=700 height=350></iframe>")
```

Which again gave me:

```
<IPython.core.display.HTML object>
```

Then I exchanged last row with:

```
IFrame("src=file:///Users/abc/m.html", width=700, height=350)
```

Which again:

```
<IPython.lib.display.IFrame at 0x112882c88>
```

When I try python's print using:

```
print("%html <iframe src=file:///Users/abc/m.html  width=700, height=350></iframe>")
```

I get 700x350 blank white window as output of the paragraph. When I try to change src to for example "https://zeppelin.apache.org/" it works well.

I feel like two things are not working properly. 
1. Folium module with zeppelin notebook which is not invoking map properly.
2. Showing local HTML page as output of zeppelin paragraph.

Does anybody tried this already? Was anybody successful to overcome this?

Comment: I don't know folium, is there any api to the html string of the folium map ? if yes, you can use `print("%html " + htmlCode)`

Comment: Thanks for advice. I was able to make it run by adding transformation of to html string and then print with python.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for advice, I was able to run it by adding:

```
html_string = m.get_root().render()

print("%html", html_string)
```

So now entire code looks like:

```
import folium

m =folium.Map(
location=[45.5236, -122.6750],
tiles='Stamen Toner',
zoom_start=13,
width=600,height=300
)
html_string = m.get_root().render()

print("%html", html_string)
```

EDIT:
using above described way was modifying appearance of entire zeppelin notebook. I used different method, using `html_string = m._repr_html_()`,which is according this link (github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/781) used in jupyter for showing HTML in iframe.

So code now:

```
import folium

m =folium.Map(
location=[45.5236, -122.6750],
tiles='Stamen Toner',
zoom_start=13,
width=600,height=300
)
html_string = m._repr_html_()
print("%html", html_string)
```